# Replace class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to accomplish the following in one line?

```
item.removeClass('oldClass')
item.addClass('newClass')
```

Something like `replaceClass` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With no further context, I'd suggest:

```
item.toggleClass('oldClass newClass');
```

If, however, you really want a `replaceClass()` method (though I can't see what it might offer, functionally):

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.replaceClass = function(classes) {
    var allClasses = classes.split(/\s+/).slice(0, 2);
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass(allClasses.join(' '));
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$('div').replaceClass('oldClass newClass');
```

```css
.oldClass {
  color: #f00;
}
.newClass {
  color: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="oldClass">This element starts with the class "oldClass"</div>
<div class="newClass">This element starts with the class "newClass"</div>
```

References:

- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to try using jquery-ui

```
switchClass('oldClass', 'newClass');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
item.removeClass('oldClass').addClass('newClass')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.theclassthatstherenow').addClass('newclasswithyourstyles');
$('.theclassthatstherenow').removeClass('theclassthatstherenow');
```

Comment: The poster is asking for a single line solution.  Can you improve your answer to meet the goal of the original question?

Comment: The best way is to do as you say, remove the class then add it again, as there's no "switching" classes in jQuery.

$('.dataItem').removeClass('ready').addClass('waiting');
You can replace multiple classes by passing in more than one class into .removeClass():

$('.dataItem').removeClass('done waiting error').addClass('ready');

Answer (score 0):

To do this in one line using jQuery, please use given code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.oldclass').addClass('newclass').removeClass('oldclass');
</script>
```